# What's the difference between "за ... от" and "в ... от"?

Tags: разница

In my russian grammar book I have the following examples:

За десять километров от Москвы. 
В ста километрах от Москвы.

Есть ли разница между "за ... от" и "в ... от"?

Спасибо заранее

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there's a small difference in usage. With the reference to a place you can use both combinations of prepositions.

> Дом отдыха находился в ста километрах/за сто километров от Москвы.

But only the first one (за...от ) can be used with the verbs of movement.

> Детей увезли  за сто километров от Москвы.

Comment: Also `в X км` is like `about X км`, and `за X km` is like `further than X km`. Latter is more about "lower" bound of the distance.

Comment: Да, можно и с этой стороны рассмотреть.